# MUI styles not getting showed properly on the initial load

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using MUI for one of my projects and I have started to face these issues. On the initial load of my app on production, the mui styles doesn't seems to get applied. For examples:

1. Switch component is not shown properly
2. Button component loads with no padding/margin even though i have used `sx` props. Though they work when i use `style` instead of `sx`.
3. Context menu also loads with improper styling.
   All the styles get fixed when I refresh the page.
   [image: How context menu renders on the first load]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Don't know what is going on without some kind of [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), all we can do is take a stab in the dark.

Comment: hey @JacobSmit Even I am not sure of what is going wrong. For some MUI components it works, but for some of them it doesn't. Wanted to know if someone else is facing this issue as well?

Comment: Are you using Next.js ?

Comment: @Yannick No.. its reactjs

Comment: @kaushalendrapandey create a small repo with the same issue, share it here. Either you won't have the issue in your recreation and you can figure out the difference, or you will have the issue and we can have a look at the code / build. Otherwise we are just going to be playing 20 questions.

Comment: @JacobSmit okay